# Django python manage.py migrate

Tags: python, django, windows

I have installed on Win7 portable Python 2.7.5.1 and Django 1.6.

I followed the first polls tutorial instructions and got an error in the migrate stage, `python manage.py migrate`:

```
C:\Natan\Dev\Portable Python 2.7.5.1\App\Scripts\mysite>..\..\python.exe manage.py migrate
Unknown command: 'migrate'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

Any idea?

Comment: Its because you are following development documentation(Which is Django 1.7), you need to follow Django 1.6 documentation (you can find it from the bottom right of the page.)

Comment: Hi, @user3041020 if any of below answers has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 17):

If you've installed 1.6, you should use the [1.6 tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/), not the one for the development version.

Comment: I run into the same, and your answer is correct, it does mention in the documentation that migrate is part of native command in 1.7 not before that.

Comment: YES!  I was just running here to say that.

Answer (score 8):

First Step, Install South:

> pip install south

Second Step, Add South to INSTALLED APPS in settings

> INSTALLED_APPS = (
>       ...,
>       'south' )

Comment: thanks, I forgot to add it to installed apps ^^, coffee time.

Answer (score 4):

Migrate will be a native command in 1.7 (which is the version you read the tutorial pages from).

For older versions, you'll have to install the third party app"South".

Answer (score 4):

All-

**This is likely caused largely by following the 1.7 (DEV version!) tutorial when we all get the last stable version (1.6!) installed by pip.**

It would not appear migrate is even a part of 1.7 in general!  Will:

***python manage.py syncdb***

Solve your problems?

So pls either follow the tutorial for the last stable version of django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/

Or follow the instructions to install the dev version of Django.

Dear Django team,
You guys are awesome.  The JS developer is very impressed.  But PLEASE resolve the discrepancy above.  Maybe default to 1.6 docs and put in red letters: Dev version here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You must install [South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to add migrate command.

`pip install south`

Comment: south has been deprecated now btw

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Django older versions before 1.7 then you should sync database by
`python manage.py syncdb`
while in new versions after 1.7 syncdb is replaced by migration. So for syncdb in new django version is replaced by :-
`python manage.py makemigrations
 python manage.py migrate`
for more type:-
`python manage.py help`