# Error while migrate postgres to Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to migrate postgres on Django, while am getting error like this:

> Unknown command: 'migrate'
>   Type 'manage.py help' for usage.

I am following this link:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial02/

Comment: What is the full command you are trying. And what version of django do you have?

Comment: i have django 1.6 version.

Comment: and i tried the command ----> python manage.py migrate

Comment: django <= 1.6 has no migration process , you have to upgrade your version

Comment: ok friend thank you..

Comment: that's an obvious dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238317/django-python-manage-py-migrate

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the tutorial link above  (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial02/) refers to Django version 1.10. You should change the version of the documentation on the bottom right of the screen to match the version you have installed, to see if that command/tutorial you are trying to run is a valid option. In this case I believe migrate was not yet an option in Django 1.6.

However, if you are using Django for the first time, I would suggest using the latest version of Django, and then also the latest version of the tutorial.