# no such table: form1_user

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I have tried all previous solutions such as syncdb, migrate, makemigrations etc. I am still not getting the program to work.

My models.py

```
class Role(models.Model):
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (1,'ADMIN'),
        (2,'HR'),
        (3,'MGR'),
        (4,'EMP'),
    )
    id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES,primary_key=True)

    def ___str___ (self):
        return self.get_id_display()

class User(AbstractUser):
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role)

class Admins(models.Model):
    user = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=Role.ROLE_CHOICES)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class HRs(models.Model):
    user = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=Role.ROLE_CHOICES)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

Then here is my views.py

```
class AdminSignUpView(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = AdminSignUpForm
    template_name = 'form1/signup_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user_type'] = 'ADMIN'
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect('/form1/forms/')

class HRSignUpView(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = HRSignUpForm
    template_name = 'form1/signup_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user_type'] = 'HR'
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self,form):
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect('/form1/forms')
```

Here is my forms.py

```
class AdminSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
    fname = forms.CharField(max_length=256)
    lname = forms.CharField(max_length=256)
    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.roles = 1
        user.save()
        admin1 = Admins.objects.create(user=user)
        admin1.first_name.add(*self.cleaned_data.get('fname'))
        admin1.last_name.add(*self.cleaned_data.get('lname'))
        return user

class HRSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
    @transaction.atomic()
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.roles = 2
        user.save()
        hr1 = HRs.objects.create(user=user)
        hr1.first_name.add(*self.cleaned_data.get('fname'))
        hr1.last_name.add(*self.cleaned_data.get('lname'))
        return user
```

Finally, here is my error -

```
OperationalError at /accounts/signup/hr/
no such table: form1_user
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/hr/
Django Version: 3.0.5
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: form1_user
```

It doesn't even show me where my mistake is in my code which makes it really hard to fix my problem. Spent hours on the internet trying to find a solution and nothing works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django python manage.py migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238317/django-python-manage-py-migrate)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ran into the same exact error. It did not seem to fix. What I did, is that I copied all the files in that folder into another folder, deleted that folder, created a new one in my project directory, then pasted everything back in (be careful with your urls.py, don't forget to change them). Then I ran the `makemigration` and `migrate` commands and it worked smoothly!

Answer (score 0):

After creating new models did you create migrations by *makemigrations* and applied those migrations by *migrate*

Comment: Yes, I did this. No success though.